# ProjError with GeoPandas (x, y, z and time must be the same size)

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, shapely

##### Problem description

Somehow, the geopandas `to_crs` method does not work.
I have `conda update --all`` and tried to run the code below in several environments (main environment, minimum environment with just geopandas installed), but it returned the same error (ProjError: x, y, z, and time must be same size).
If someone has any idea to fix this, I appreciate your kind help.

##### Code Sample, a copy-pastable example

```py
### to crs method check
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326" # original crs
gdf = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:6668") # convert to new crs
print(gdf)
```

```
ProjError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 14
     12 gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
     13 gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326" # original crs
---> 14 gdf = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:6668") # convert to new crs
     15 print(gdf)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py:1364, in GeoDataFrame.to_crs(self, crs, epsg, inplace)
   1362 else:
   1363     df = self.copy()
-> 1364 geom = df.geometry.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg)
   1365 df.geometry = geom
   1366 if not inplace:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py:1124, in GeoSeries.to_crs(self, crs, epsg)
   1047 def to_crs(self, crs=None, epsg=None):
   1048     """Returns a ``GeoSeries`` with all geometries transformed to a new
   1049     coordinate reference system.
   1050 
   (...)
   1121 
   1122     """
   1123     return GeoSeries(
-> 1124         self.values.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg), index=self.index, name=self.name
   1125     )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\array.py:779, in GeometryArray.to_crs(self, crs, epsg)
    775     return self
    777 transformer = Transformer.from_crs(self.crs, crs, always_xy=True)
--> 779 new_data = vectorized.transform(self.data, transformer.transform)
    780 return GeometryArray(new_data, crs=crs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_vectorized.py:1114, in transform(data, func)
   1111 result[~has_z] = set_coordinates(data[~has_z].copy(), np.array(new_coords_z).T)
   1113 coords_z = get_coordinates(data[has_z], include_z=True)
-> 1114 new_coords_z = func(coords_z[:, 0], coords_z[:, 1], coords_z[:, 2])
   1115 result[has_z] = set_coordinates(data[has_z].copy(), np.array(new_coords_z).T)
   1117 return result

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyproj\transformer.py:430, in Transformer.transform(self, xx, yy, zz, tt, radians, errcheck, direction)
    428     intime = None
    429 # call pj_transform.  inx,iny,inz buffers modified in place.
--> 430 self._transformer._transform(
    431     inx,
    432     iny,
    433     inz=inz,
    434     intime=intime,
    435     direction=direction,
    436     radians=radians,
    437     errcheck=errcheck,
    438 )
    439 # if inputs were lists, tuples or floats, convert back.
    440 outx = _convertback(xisfloat, xislist, xistuple, inx)

File pyproj/_transformer.pyx:459, in pyproj._transformer._Transformer._transform()

ProjError: x, y, z, and time must be same size
```

##### Output of `geopandas.show_versions()`

### SYSTEM INFO

python     : 3.9.16 (main, Mar  8 2023, 10:39:24) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable : C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\python.exe
machine    : Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0

### GEOS, GDAL, PROJ INFO

GEOS       : 3.8.0
GEOS lib   : None
GDAL       : 3.6.2
GDAL data dir: None
PROJ       : 6.2.1
PROJ data dir: C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\Library\share\proj

### PYTHON DEPENDENCIES

geopandas  : 0.12.2
numpy      : 1.24.3
pandas     : 1.5.3
pyproj     : 2.6.1.post1
shapely    : 2.0.1
fiona      : 1.9.1
geoalchemy2: None
geopy      : 2.2.0
matplotlib : 3.7.1
mapclassify: 2.5.0
pygeos     : None
pyogrio    : None
psycopg2   : None
pyarrow    : None
rtree      : 1.0.1

Comment: I have no issue running your code. According to the error message: `File pyproj/_transformer.pyx:459, in pyproj._transformer._Transformer._transform() ...`, the module `pyproj` may cause the errors. Maybe it is too old. Try upgrade it and rerun.

Comment: I ran `conda update` and the pyoroj got 2.6.1.post1. But maybe you are right because I found that the latest pyproj version is 3.5.0. I will check the dependency conflicts...

Comment: I updated `pyproj 3.5.0` and rerun the code, and it worked!
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Glad to here it. Now I turn my comment into an answer since it is confirmed by your comments. You can thank me by clicking it to accept it as a valid answer. By doing so, you earn 2 reputation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no issue running your code.

According to the error message:

```
File pyproj/_transformer.pyx:459, in pyproj._transformer._Transformer._transform() ...,
```

the module `pyproj` may cause the errors. Maybe it is too old (version 2.6.1.post1). Try upgrade it to more recent version and rerun.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error!

But I successfully resolved it through upgrading the pyproj.

`pip install --upgrade pyproj`

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert to a valid CRS:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"  
gdf = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:3857")  
print(gdf)
```

which gives

```
           City    Country  Latitude  Longitude  \
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina    -34.58     -58.66   
1      Brasilia     Brazil    -15.78     -47.91   
2      Santiago      Chile    -33.45     -70.66   
3        Bogota   Colombia      4.60     -74.08   
4       Caracas  Venezuela     10.48     -66.86   

                            geometry  
0  POINT (-6530001.330 -4106950.295)  
1  POINT (-5333316.804 -1779259.486)  
2  POINT (-7865835.219 -3955187.399)  
3    POINT (-8246547.878 512620.654)  
4   POINT (-7442821.154 1173188.376)  
​
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
However, your code also returns the same error in my environment (ProjError : x, y, z, and time must be same size)...